# how can I multiple tapping with single marker

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, sdk, marker

by tapping, it makes marker infinity. i want to one marker where I tapped. over and over again. not with lots markers.

[image]

I used MapView.clean(). but it delete every markers.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
{
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
        marker.position.latitude = coordinate.latitude
        marker.position.longitude = coordinate.longitude
        print("hello")
        print(markerr.position.latitude)
        let ULlocation = markerr.position.latitude
        let ULlgocation = markerr.position.longitude
        print(ULlocation)
        print(ULlgocation)
        marker.map = self.mapView
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the marker outside the `didTapAt coordinate` method and change it's coordinates in this method

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    let marker = GMSMarker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        marker.map = self.mapView
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
    {
        marker.position = coordinate
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @smoo.an In didTapAt coordinate method?

Comment: top part.
let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)